# Can an ASP.NET 2.0 WebApp be configured as a child application under an MVC3 website in IIS7?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis-7, webforms

I have an MVC3 website setup in IIS7, lets say the URL is http://devtest.com, and I would like to setup an ASP.NET 2.0 webapp as a child application.  My goal is to hit a URL like http://devtest.com/childapp.

While the MVC app is working fine, when attempting to navigate to the child app, I get an error:
*"Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."*

Is this type of configuration even possible, and if not, can anybody suggest an alternative setup?

Comment: What have you used so far? A virtual directory?

Comment: The child application will inherit web.config file settings from the parent application and you will have to specify inheritInChildApplications="false" based upon your needs in the parent web.config file.  Search for "nested asp.net mvc application in iis".

Comment: Yup I made a rookie mistake by adding this to the child web.config, instead of the parent web.config.  This fixed it right away.

Comment: @Mitul you should post your comment as an answer and get the points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The child application will inherit web.config file settings from the parent application and you will have to specify inheritInChildApplications="false" based upon your needs in the parent web.config file.

links:
1. [Nested ASP.NET 'application' within IIS inheriting parent config values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4144117/nested-asp-net-application-within-iis-inheriting-parent-config-values)
2. [Problems hosting multiple ASP.Net MVC3 applications in an IIS7.5 website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10521059/problems-hosting-multiple-asp-net-mvc3-applications-in-an-iis7-5-website)